# Setting up a full node while getting err="etherbase must be explicitly specified"

Tags: go-ethereum, bsc, binance

I was trying to setup a full node and getting err="etherbase must be explicitly specified".

I followed the steps here https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/fullnode.html and syncing from snapshot, it was running for a day or two and suddenly throw me the error that etherbase is not specified.

If I understand correctly, running a full node is just acting as a witness node and no etherbase is required? Anyway, how to resolve this issue and getting my full node properly running? Should I follow the steps in the "syncing from genesis" section and init from the genesis.json?

Answer (score 0):

The problem can come from adding multiple account in your genesis file. or you may need to specify with --miner.etherbase 0x123...